# SQL Fill Missing Values

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

i have an existing table that looks like this

```
date | days_num | value
2023-01-01 | 0 | 2
2023-01-01 | 1 | 3
2023-01-01 | 2 | 4
2023-01-01 | 3 | 4
2023-01-01 | 4 | 2
2023-01-01 | 5 | 1

2023-01-02 | 0 | 2
2023-01-02 | 1 | 3
2023-01-02 | 2 | 4
2023-01-02 | 3 | 2
2023-01-02 | 4 | 2

2023-01-03 | 0 | 3
2023-01-03 | 1 | 4
2023-01-03 | 2 | 5
```

targer is fill or complete the missing days_num to certain number eg. 5, for all of my dates, then set value to NULL. is it possible to query it?

```
date | days_num | value
2023-01-01 | 0 | 2
2023-01-01 | 1 | 3
2023-01-01 | 2 | 4
2023-01-01 | 3 | 4
2023-01-01 | 4 | 2
2023-01-01 | 5 | 1

2023-01-02 | 0 | 2
2023-01-02 | 1 | 3
2023-01-02 | 2 | 4
2023-01-02 | 3 | 2
2023-01-02 | 4 | 2
2023-01-02 | 5 | NULL *

2023-01-03 | 0 | 3
2023-01-03 | 1 | 4
2023-01-03 | 2 | 5
2023-01-03 | 3 | NULL *
2023-01-03 | 4 | NULL *
2023-01-03 | 5 | NULL *
```

Comment: You have already asked this question and it was closed.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to generate dates with `sequence` between `min` and `max`.
Then you need to generate `days_nums` with `sequence` again.
Then get cartesian product of `dates` and `days_nums`.

Then you need to run an `outer join`.

```sql
SELECT seq.date, seq.days_num, NULL as value
FROM ( 
  SELECT * FROM (    
        VALUES 
        (DATE '2023-01-01', 0, 2),
        (DATE '2023-01-01', 1, 3),
        (DATE '2023-01-01', 2, 4),
        (DATE '2023-01-01', 3, 4),
        (DATE '2023-01-01', 4, 2),
        (DATE '2023-01-01', 5, 1),
        (DATE '2023-01-02', 0, 2),
        (DATE '2023-01-02', 1, 3),
        (DATE '2023-01-02', 2, 4),
        (DATE '2023-01-02', 3, 2),
        (DATE '2023-01-02', 4, 2),
        (DATE '2023-01-03', 0, 3),
        (DATE '2023-01-03', 1, 4),
        (DATE '2023-01-03', 2, 5)
    ) AS t (date, days_num, value)
) AS ed
RIGHT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM 
  UNNEST(sequence(DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-01-03', interval '1' day)) t(date),
  UNNEST(sequence(0, 5)) t(days_num)
) AS seq ON ed.date = seq.date AND seq.days_num = ed.days_num
WHERE ed.date IS NULL AND ed.days_num IS NULL
ORDER BY seq.date, seq.days_num
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2023-01-02 00:00:00.000 5 NULL
2023-01-03 00:00:00.000 3 NULL
2023-01-03 00:00:00.000 4 NULL
2023-01-03 00:00:00.000 5 NULL
```

Comment: You can simplify your data initialization with `VALUES`.